# jQuery: Thinking on() instead of live() ,propagations on Dynamically Generated Stuffs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, propagation

Got this `HTML`:

```
<div id="mother">
   <select id="sel" name="sel">
     <option value="1">Un</option>

     <option value="2">Deux</option>
     <option value="3">Trois</option>
</select>

<input id="in" name="in"/>
</div>
```

The `mother` is in the page but both children, `select` and `input` are dynamically generated

Tried to call them by using something like:

```
$('body').on('blur change','#mother input, #mother select',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
    })
```

`Javascript` is saying nothing all..

How can this be best done using `on()` instead of `live()`? ... because with `live()` it was kinda easier to figure out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.live() is deprecated and removed, don't use it at all
[version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

use on like this

```
$('body').on('blur change', '#mother input, #mother select', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I think kinda misplaced the `,` (coma) and the `  ` (space)... Thanks for the reminder... Worked perfectly like VOODOO!!

Answer (score 1):

Your events must be space separated: `blur change`, *not* `blur,change`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this sintax :

```
<div id="mother">
   <select id="sel" name="sel">
     <option value="1">1</option>

     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input id="in" name="in"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('body').on({
        blur: function () {
            alert("blur");
        },
        change: function () {
            alert("change");
        }
    }, '#mother input, #mother select');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FccfN/1/

Comment: How will you `alert(the attr('id'))` of the required elements with this chemical formula?

Comment: you can use $(this) : alert("blur id = " + $(this).attr("id"));
update jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FccfN/2/

Comment: Man Your Chemical formula looks super,never thought of that, gonna use it  somewhere in the project... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong elsewhere in your page. I created a Fiddle that shows this working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/evictor/Dnsm8/

```
<div id="mother">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('blur change','#mother input, #mother select',function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
    });

    $('<input id="test" />').appendTo('#mother');
});
```

Comment: The Problem was misplacing  both the coma and the gap or space... after having it done correctly as displayed  by **Antonis** it worked perfectly like VOODOO

Comment: That's exactly what I posted and you said it wasn't right lol. Oh well.

Comment: Sorry Man... I think he kinda displayed it a little more profound with myCodesWithMistakesIncluded (CWMI)... That's why he won the lottery, but thanks a millionX for the prompt response.